# C++ Scope Resolution Issue

Tags: c++, matrix, scope, operator-overloading

Yesterday my class had a laboratory exam where-in we had to make a matrix class and overload the `operation+()`. I thought that I had it correct until I went to go do my unit testing... I know this is a lot of text; however, I spent the remainder of the lab trying to figure out what was going wrong and could NOT figure out why the Temporary Object Matrix was going out of scope prior to the assignment operator call.

Code as follows:

**Matrix Header**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Matrix
{
Public:
// Constructor and Destructor Suite
Matrix(int x, int y); // Lab TA stated that Matricies would never go above two dimensions
~Matrix(); 

// Access and Mutation
void set(int row, int column, int value); // This function sets the value of a given matrix coordinate at row, column to value
int get(int row, int column) const; // This function returns the value of a matrix at row, column

Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& Q)
{
    cout << "Called Assignment" << endl;
    int r, c;
    r = Q.rows; c = Q.columns;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < c; k++)
        {
            cout << "Address of Calling Objet pointer Int: " << this->pMatrixOfInt[i][k] << setw(5) << *this->pMatrixOfInt[i][k] << endl;
            cout << "Address of Reference Object: " << Q.pMatrixOfInt[i][k] << setw(5) << *Q.pMatrixOfInt[i][k] << endl;
            *(this->pMatrixOfInt[i][k]) = *(Q.pMatrixOfInt[i][k]);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
const Matrix operator+(const Matrix& Q);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Matrix& Q);
friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Matrix& Q);
private:
int rows, columns;
int* pMatrixOfInt[50][50]; // Specification document said that these values would never go above 50
};
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
/*
Matrix Class Definition
14 March 2014
*/
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
// Constructor
Matrix::Matrix(int x, int y)
{
    cout << "Constructor Called" << endl;
    this->rows=x;
    this->columns=y;
    for (int i=rows-1; i>=0; i--)           // If X and Y are both 50 then the starting value
    {                                       // for i and k should be 49 because of how arrays
        for (int k=columns-1; k>=0; k--)    // are indexed. Hence the rows-1
        {
            pMatrixOfInt[i][k] = new int;
        }
    }
}
// Destructor
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    cout << "Destructor Called" << endl;
    for (int i=rows-1; i>=0; i--)           // If X and Y are both 50 then the starting value
    {                                       // for i and k should be 49 because of how arrays
        for (int k=columns-1; k>=0; k--)    // are indexed. Hence the rows-1
        {
            delete pMatrixOfInt[i][k];
        }
    }
}
// Access and Mutation
void Matrix::set(int row, int column, int value)
{
    *pMatrixOfInt[row][column] = value;
}
int Matrix::get(int row, int column) const
{
    return *pMatrixOfInt[row][column];
}
// Overloaded Addition Operator (Possible Scope Problem)
const Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& Q)
{
    cout << "Addition Operator Called" << endl;
    int rows, columns;
    rows = Q.rows;
    columns = Q.columns;
    Matrix newMatrix(rows, columns);
    cout << "newMatrix Rows: " << newMatrix.rows << " -- newMatrix columns: " << newMatrix.columns << endl; // Make a new matrix. Constructor will initialize the pointer Matrix
    int newValue;
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<columns; k++)
        {
            newValue = this->get(i,k);
            newValue += Q.get(i,k);
            newMatrix.set(i,k, newValue);
            cout << setw(5) << newMatrix.get(i, k);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return newMatrix;
}
// Friend definitions for i/ostreams.
ostream&::operator<<(ostream& output, const Matrix& Q)
{
    for (int r = 0; r<Q.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<Q.columns; c++) // hahaha
        {
            output << setw(4) << Q.get(r,c);
        }
        output << "\n";
    }
    return output;
}
istream&::operator>>(istream& input, Matrix& Q)
{
    int value;
    for (int r = 0; r<Q.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<Q.columns; c++)
        {
            input >> value;
            Q.set(r,c,value);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

When I tried to do something like this:

```
newMatrix = oldMatrixA + oldMatrixB;
cout << newMatrix;
```

I received the following series of outputs and then a BLOCK_HEADER_ERROR:

```
Addition Operator Called
0   1   2   3
1   3   5   7
Destructor Called
Assignment Called
Lots of output here regarding address of calling object and value along with the reference object and value of that too
!!!BLOCK_HEADER_ERROR!!!
```

*Can anyone tell me why the Temporary Object returned by the addition operator is going out of scope prior to the assignment operator even though they are on the same line and newMatrix is a return object and thus should not be destroyed until the scope calling it calls for its destruction?*

Thank you in advance for your help, I didn't sleep well last night because the TA made me turn in work that I knew was bugged and I haven't been able to figure out the problem.

I know that it's a lot of code and this is the longest question I've posted to StackOverflow ever; however, I like sleeping well and I don't think I'll rest soundly until I know what's going wrong.

Comment: No, you are not doing it right: **Why are you storing pointers to ints instead of ints?** Thats dddoesn't make sense at all. Also, using an static array (i.e. a compile-time sized array) and get the dimensions of the matrix at runtime doesn't make sense too. Finally, you should use `std::size_t` intead of integers for sizes.

Comment: Also, **don't return by const value!!!** That only serves for breaking some posible compiler optimizations.

Comment: Because it was a laboratory exam, my hands were tied in some respects. This was one of them. I'm only in my first year of programming in C++ so I didn't know about ``std::size_t`` (and need to learn about it). 

As for return by const, again, hands were tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use pointers to store the values? Use plain integers instead and you are fine.

At first think about the "too early" destruction:

In your code you actually have two temporaries (if no return value optimization takes place):
The first one is `newValue` and the second one your rvalue temporary that gets returned by `operator+`.

After a copy of `newValue` to the temporary rvalue has been made `newValue` is destructed (the message you see).

Second problem is: You did not specify a custom copy constructor (think about the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)). Hence the rvalue temporary copy has all the pointers to the integers that you freed when destructing `newValue`.

If you can't use plain integers, then you have to write your own copy constructor that really copies (allocates new integers for the new matrix).

If you can use plain integers, then use them and everything is fine (no need for custom destructor/copy constructor/copy assignment operator)

An example copy constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &other) {
    this->rows=other.rows;
    this->columns=other.columns;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
            // allocate a new integer with the value 
            // copied from the other matrix
            pMatrixOfInt[row][column] = new int(*other.pMatrixOfInt[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I explained in response to @Manu343726, my hands were tied in respect to some of the methods that could be used, ergo the use of ``int* matrixOfInt[50][50]``.

I'm not sure what you mean by ``newValue`` is producing the destructor method because the message is only produced when a Matrix destructor is called... unless you mean that ``newValue`` is the temporary rValue produced by the ``operator+()``? In Matrix.set() I use the ``*matrixOfInt[i][k] = newValue`` to make sure that the value of newValue is written to the address of the int*.

Overloaded Assignment != Custom Copy??

Comment: Then you need to implement the copy constructor and copy assignment or your code is wrong. The default copy operations as done by the compiler are not appropriate and cause the errors in your case.

Comment: `newValue` goes out of scope when `operator+` returns, so the destructor is called on it. You need to distinguish `operator=` (which you excplicitly used and implemented correctly as far as I can see) and the copy constructor `Matrix(const Matrix&)` which is called implicitly to return the value of `newValue` into the temporary return value of `operator+`

Comment: This is probably why my code does not work correctly! I have not been taught about the copy constructor and don't know how I would go about writing one. I'm looking at that Wikipedia entry and trying to make sense of it (and failing). If it's not too much to ask, could you write a short copy constructor example in your original answer so I can select it?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that you will be able to do this on your own. The copy constructor is basically a mix of the constructor and copy assignment. Still I will post an example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nobody. I always learn better by example!

Comment: @karnesJ.R: One note about your copy assignment operator: You forgot to update the `rows` and `columns` of the matrix being assigned to (imagine a 2x2 matrix gets assigned to a (former) 10x10 matrix)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49813/discussion-between-karnesj-r-and-nobody)

Comment: I implemented the copy constructor and included a debug output ``cout << "Entered Copy Constructor\n";`` and re-compiled the program but did not see the copy constructor called... so I changed my call in main to be ``Matrix addMatrix(test1 + test2);``. This invoked the overloaded copy, but still did not solve the problem because the addition Temporary Matrix was destroyed by scope before being able to passed in to the Overloaded Copy. I think that our first assumption was incorrect.

Do you need to see the source.cpp?

Comment: @karnesJ.R: Does the source.cpp differ from the text you gave here? If so, please post it so we can see if there is any error in it. Even if the (correct) copy constructor does not solve the problem it is necessary for completely correct code. Also: Which compiler do you use? (or better: do you use C++11 features?) And another important question: Did you try to debug the program and see where the error is coming from/where the outputs are triggered?

Comment: @karnesJ.R: I have tried to compile your code and there are some flaws: `Public:` has to be all lowercase. `ostream&::operator<<` should actually be `ostream& operator<<` (I am suprised my compiler only gave a warning and no error about this). About style: never write `using namespace ...` in a header! (This can have unwanted side effects). Finally after some corrections I got your code to run and the output order was: Constructor (`oldMatrixA`) Constructor (`oldMatrixB`) Addition Constructor Destructor Destructor Destructor. Notice the lack of assignment in my run.

Comment: I have solved the error with a combination of your advice (for which I am going to re-select the answer) and something Manu said about "Don't return by Constant Reference." As soon as I switched the code from ``const Matrix& operator+(const Matrix& Q)`` to ``Matrix operator+(const Matrix& Q)`` the code functioned as intended.

Comment: @karnesJ.R: You did not post this code. Your code said: `const Matrix` and not `const Matrix&` (note the missing `&`). That explains the problem: You return a reference to the local instance `newMatrix`. Never do that! At the end of the function the local instance goes out of scope -> gets destructed but you return the reference to it and hence access the wrong memory.

Comment: I don't understand why the code that is posted is incorrect. I definitely didn't define my operators<< and >> with istream&::<< because this is improper style (and just plain wrong). Something happened between ctrl-C and ctrl-V that I can't explain. Sorry for the headache!